# Calling different solvers based on the constraint type chosen

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I want to give the user the option to choose between three different optimization methods coded with VBA: Profit, Power, and Machine Hours.  Each method will use different constraints.  The user clicks the drop down menu and selects the method, and then hits an Optimize button that calls this program.

```
Public Sub RunOptimization()
Dim targetVal As Single
Dim rownum, result, i As Integer
Dim constraintType As String

constraintType = ActiveSheet.Range("F16").Value

If (constraintType = "Profit") Then

    '# first delete the output worksheet
    If Not GetWorksheet(OUTPUT_SHEET) Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverReset"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/functions/solverok-function
    '# 1 - maximize
    '# 2 - minimize
    '# 3 - match a specific value
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverOk", "model!H33", 1, "model!N11", "GRG Nonlinear"  ' set up new analysis

     ' add constraints -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/solveradd-function
     '# 1 : <=
     '# 2 : =
     '# 3 : >=
     '# Add the constraints here
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!H14", 1, "model!H13"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!K14", 1, "model!K13"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!N14", 1, "model!N13"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!P21", 1, "model!P20"

    result = Application.Run("Solver.xlam!SolverSolve", True)

    If result <= 3 Then
        Debug.Print "Solution found"

        '# this copies the results to the output page
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = OUTPUT_SHEET
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B1").Value = "Optimized output"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B3").Value = "Units of A"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B4").Value = "Units of B"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B5").Value = "Units of C"

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("h11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        '# copy B units
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("k11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        '# copy C units
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("n11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Else
       'Call MsgBox("Solver was unable to find a solution.", vbExclamation, "SOLUTION NOT FOUND")
       Call MsgBox("Solver unable to find a solution")
    End If

ElseIf (constraintType = "Power") Then

        '# first delete the output worksheet
    If Not GetWorksheet(OUTPUT_SHEET) Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverReset"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/functions/solverok-function
    '# 1 - maximize
    '# 2 - minimize
    '# 3 - match a specific value
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverOk", "model!H33", 1, "model!N11", "GRG Nonlinear"  ' set up new analysis

     ' add constraints -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/solveradd-function
     '# 1 : <=
     '# 2 : =
     '# 3 : >=
     '# Add the constraints here
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!H14", 1, "model!H13"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!K14", 1, "model!K13"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!N14", 1, "model!N13"

    result = Application.Run("Solver.xlam!SolverSolve", True)

    If result <= 3 Then
        Debug.Print "Solution found"

        '# this copies the results to the output page
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = OUTPUT_SHEET
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B1").Value = "Optimized output"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B3").Value = "Units of A"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B4").Value = "Units of B"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("B5").Value = "Units of C"

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("h11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        '# copy B units
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("k11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        '# copy C units
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MODEL_SHEET).Range("n11").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHEET).Range("c5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Else
       'Call MsgBox("Solver was unable to find a solution.", vbExclamation, "SOLUTION NOT FOUND")
       Call MsgBox("Solver unable to find a solution")
    End If

ElseIf (constraintType = "Machine hours") Then
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Private Function GetWorksheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set GetWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName)
End Function
```

The first method runs fine when selected (profit), however when I select and run the second method (Power), it outputs the same answer as the first.

The code is running properly (its skipping over the Profit If Then and running through the power), however it is still using the Profit constraints.

I haven't set up the third option yet (Machine Hours).  I'm trying to get the first two functioning first.

Comment: Step through the code with `F8`.  That way, you can go line-by-line and see where the code is diverting from what you expect.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the suggestion.  So the code is running properly (its skipping over the Profit If Then and running through the power), however it is still being constrained by a constraint I have in the Profit constraints.  Do you think my solver reset is not set up properly?  Thats the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The constraint below which is listed in the Profit Solver continues to be a factor even when I skip the Profit and run the Power Solver...I cant seem to properly reset solver, any idea why?

 Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", "model!P21", 1, "model!P20"